# Hourly total of table entries over one day

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.0

I have a table `mytable` with an event time field called evtime.  To summarize the number of entries per day, I use:

```
select date_trunc('day',evtime),
       count(1) as entries 
from mytable 
group by date_tunc('day',evtime);
```

That works fine.  But now, for one specific date, I'd like to see the totals per hour.

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
select date_trunc('hour', evtime),
       count(*) as entries 
from mytable 
where date_trunc('day', evtime) = $yourdate
group by date_tunc('hour', evtime);
```

Or, it occurs to me that you want the summary by day on most days and by hour on one.  If so:

```
select (case when date_trunc('day', evtime) = $yourdate
             then date_trunc('hour', evtime)
             else date_trunc('day', evtime)
        end) as day_hour,
       count(*) as entries 
from mytable 
group by day_hour;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Gordon.  That did it.